# ASP.NET (or IIS) gives wrong virtual path when using Server.MapPath

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

When attempting to get the path to my App_Data folder, it looks at the wrong path on the server.  I have a website setup with a virtual path of C:\Projects\MyProject.  App folder exists in c:\Projects\MyProject\App_Data.

This code:

```
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
```

On my IIS server trys to navigate to C:\App_Data\Uploads\filename.ext.  Why would it try to navigate to the C:\ root?

.NET 4, IIS 7, Web Forms and MVC mixed

Comment: Do you have a custom VirtualPathProvider in your application?

Comment: No, I searched the application and it appears that is not being used

Comment: Try using .NET source-stepping into the Server.MapPath call and trace where the bad path is coming from. It isn't hard to configure .NET source code in VS.